# Is there anything which can influence gcc build of the same code?

Tags: gcc

For example we have some source code.
And two different builds by the same GCC of the same source code gives you different CPU load for this programm

Is it possible that something can affect compiling except for source code and gcc options?
P.s. i guess it's stupid question but anyway....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't update the rest of you system between the gcc invocations, gcc should produce identical executables. You can check if this is the case by comparing them:

```
$ gcc ...
$ mv my_program my_program.1
$ gcc ...
$ cmp -l my_program.1 my_program
```

If this does not produce any output, the executables are identical.

However, as you write "CPU load", you seem to refer to the run time of the program, and a lot of things can influence that. For example:

- system load from other processes
- time of day (random numbers)
- memory layout (library address randomization)

If the difference is only a few percent, that's usually due to limited measuring accuracy. If the difference is large, I suggest you use a profiler and/or post more details about your program.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I was sure that it's supposed to be like that but i just felt to ask that.